# Using Siesta with a non-restful API

Tags: ios, swift3, siesta-swift

I know this is probably a long-shot, but is it possible to use Siesta with a completely non-RESTful API? The API I have to work with (and is not in my control so sadly cannot change) requires every request to be a POST request regardless of whether it is purely retrieving data or not.

I've had a read through the question/answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41832911/configure-request-method-for-a-siesta-resource) which gives me a glimmer of hope, however the big difference between that question and mine is the endpoints of each request. For the API I'm using, they're all the same :(

Every single request must POST to `/api/api_post.php`, and everything else is specified as a parameter supplied in the request.

Obviously I can roll my own request wrapper to handle this, but I'd love to be able to use some of the functionality provided by Siesta and not have to worry about all the annoyances of dealing with networking. Is there any way of doing this at all, or am I out of luck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your app work with an imaginary REST API, then transform that to non-restful requests underneath Siesta’s nose. (For example, `GET /foo/3` might be transformed to `POST /api/api_post.php` with `item=foo&id=3`.) It’s a bit of a hassle, but it does get you the benefits of Siesta even for non-REST APIs.

There are two ways to implement this:

1. Use [`mutateRequests(…)`](https://bustoutsolutions.github.io/siesta/api/Structs/Configuration.html#//apple_ref/swift/Method/mutateRequests(with:)) to rewrite requests. This lets you arbitrarily alter the `URLRequest` before it’s sent.
2. Write your own [`NetworkingProvider`](http://bustoutsolutions.github.io/siesta/api/Protocols/NetworkingProvider.html). This is a bit more of a hassle, but gives more wholesale control of the rewriting. This approach might be more suitable if, for example, you need to rewrite responses as well, or if you have to turn one virtual request into multiple real ones.

More in the [discussion here](https://github.com/bustoutsolutions/siesta/issues/81).

Comment: Ah perfect thank you! I'll have a read through those, hopefully I can get something configured :)